# GNUplot 2D time animation

Tags: python, csv, graph, gnuplot, line

I have a csv file that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vZF2.png), and am attempting to render each x, y coordinate accordingly to the given timestamp (with interpolated motion in between each point). Absolutely no experience with gnuplot so not sure how I'd go about this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you think it is not a duplicate, please show your script and specify where the problem is.